# localStorage cleared after refresh

Tags: php, javascript, json, local-storage

I have a problem with saving data to the localstorage of the browser.

I have a php file and a switch. When the type is "favorites" I make a create a button and send the json data to a function "save" in my javascript.

```
case 'favorites':
            $session = $m->session;

            $data = json_encode((array)$session);

            echo "<a onclick='save(".$data.")' style='cursor:pointer;' class='metacell'>
                    <img src='".buildUri('images/icons/favorite.png')."' width='16' />
                    <span>Add to favorites</span>
                    </a>";
            break;
```

This is my javascript:

```
function save(data)
    {
        var thedata = data;

        // STORE THE ABOVE DATA IN LOCALSTORAGE
        localStorage.setItem('data', "testje");
    }
```

I'm currently testing with just some text "testje". When i push the button it goes in localstorage but when I refresh the page its gone ...

Does anbody know how this comes?

Comment: Can you provide us the whole JS code? Make sure that you don't override your localStorage when you load the page.

Comment: Try  `localStorage.data= "testje";`

Comment: check it `<a onclick='save(".$data.")' style='cursor:pointer;' class='metacell'>` in firebug.

Comment: Are you sure you test in in PHP ? If you test in while opening the file in `file://`, then it can't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a HTML attribute to transport the value albeit you do not do any HTML encoding of the value. This will likely break your code. If you would verify your HTML source code you might have seen that. So validate first (install a browser-extension that does this for you automatically).

Also as written you need to HTML encode the *onclick* attribute value:

```
echo "<a onclick='save(", htmlspecialchars($data), ")' s [...]
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

http://php.net/htmlspecialchars

Comment: What do you mean with validate first? (and what browser-extension? ...)

Comment: With validate first I mean HTML validation. Which browser are you using then I can show you an extension.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 var thedata ;

function save(data)
{
    thedata = data;

    localStorage.thedata="testje";
}
```

Comment: localStorage.thedata="testje";

Answer (score 0):

```
function save(data)
    {

        // STORE THE ABOVE DATA IN LOCALSTORAGE
        window.localStorage.setItem('data', data);
    }
```

Try that!
localStorage might have become a global variable ( in the context of the page) and wasn't pointing to the real localStorage at all

Comment: That doesn't do nothing at all. It don't even add it to the localstorage. Strange....

Comment: Are you using a browser that supports localStorage? Can you do a check if if(window.localStorage){ alert(' I have storage');}

Comment: I am using Google Chrome and I get an alert "I have storage". The strange is that he adds it but when I refresh its gone.

Comment: This is very odd, could you supply a jsfiddle link perhaps? It would seem that when you load the page something is happening with the localStorage, as in removing the property from localStorage